# while loop doesn't terminate due to empty strings

Tags: python

While loop doesn't terminate because temp variable always receives an empty string which is never false.  How can I avoid this?

```
city_temp = []
temp = mean_temp.readline().strip().split(",")
while temp:
    city_temp.append(temp)

    temp = mean_temp.readline().strip().split(",")
```

Comment: Post the complate code

Comment: Empty strings *are* false.

Comment: Empty strings are [falsy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Please make a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: The problem isn't that empty strings aren't falsey (they are). The problem is that `['']`, a list containing an empty string, is not falsey.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that empty strings aren't falsey (they are). The problem is that `['']`, a list containing an empty string, is not falsey. Why not read your string into a variable and check if that is empty, rather than splitting it immediately?

```
city_temp = []
line = mean_temp.readline().strip()
while line:
    city_temp.append(line.split(','))
    line = mean_temp.readline().strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your "temp" is a list, which if not empty, will evaluate to True.

Can you use something like:

```
for t in temp:
    city_temp.append(t)
```

?

Comment: You're talking about a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#lists). An [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is something different in Python.

Comment: Right!  Some antics.  Thanks.

Comment: This will append empty strings to `city_temp` when the line is empty.